# Create a vector that contains the first 10 powers of 2, then the first 10 powers of 3 by R language

Tags: r

I try to use `x <- rep(2,10)` , but I don't know what I should do next. Can anyone give me some advice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: R is vectorized. Evaluate `2^(1:10)` and see what you get. That should be enough of a hint.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `rep`, because, for example, R recycles the base `2` as the power of 1, 2, 3...10 is calculated, the latter expressed in R shorthand as the vector `1:10`

```
2^(1:10)
#[1]    2    4    8   16   32   64  128  256  512 1024
3^(1:10)
#[1]     3     9    27    81   243   729  2187  6561 19683 59049
```

Parantheses are necessary around `(1:10)`; otherwise, R would interpret this as simply wanting the vector 2:10

```
2^1:10
#[1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Comment: Another option: `c(t(outer(2:3, 1:10, FUN = '^')))`

Comment: A good answer provides some explanation of why it works and why it improves on the original attempt.

Answer (score 0):

```
sapply(2:3, function(v) v**(1:10))
```

gives

```
      [,1]  [,2]
 [1,]    2     3
 [2,]    4     9
 [3,]    8    27
 [4,]   16    81
 [5,]   32   243
 [6,]   64   729
 [7,]  128  2187
 [8,]  256  6561
 [9,]  512 19683
[10,] 1024 59049
```